Async method lacks 'await' operator
.Net 4.8 project with C# and trying to tidy this function:
public class AuthorizationServiceProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
       public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext Context)
       {
          Context.Validated();
       }
}

It is flagging with this async method lacks 'await' operator, should I create some fake/dummy value/logic just to implement the await keyword? which would remove the warning on build? not a solution but would solve this
What is the best practice?

Change async Task to void.

@PoulBak See that override keyword? I don't think changing the return type is gonna cut it.

correct, this didnt work

You're right, didn't see the override. Still the async should go.

The simplest solution might be to remove the async keyword and return Task.CompletedTask.
public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext Context)
{
    Context.Validated();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

But I don't recommend that at all. The caveat is exception handling.
Lets assume that this function throws an exception.
In this case, you must handle them, both when calling the method and when await on the result.
Maybe await and method invoke will be on the same line of code. In that case there is no difference.
But what about a scenario of caching the task and awaiting them later?
var t = instance.ValidateClientAuthentication(...); // synchronous exceptions occur here

// some other code

await t; // asynchronous exceptions are unwrapped here

In that case you need two exception handling blocks - and that's why I don't recommend to remove the async keyword.
You should suppress this compiler warning and use async wherever the signature forces an async implementation. Even Stephen Cleary was propagating that approach:
#pragma warning disable CS1998 // Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously
public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext Context)
#pragma warning restore CS1998 // Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously
{
    Context.Validated();
}


add this to your method:
await Task.CompletedTask;

UPDATE:
Just to be clear, this is standard practice, and the simplest solution to the issue.

Or better yet, remove async and then it's just return Task.CompletedTask;.

So had a quick google on this... wouldnt await Task.CompletedTask be better as it wouldnt change the signature? (as this function isnt mentioned anywhere on the project) and as its an auth, possibly coming from the UI, which would need changed then. I just dont know what the side effects are of changing the signature

To the best of my knowledge the async is not part of the signature ... you should be able to remove it with no side effects.

async is not part of the signature, but you shouldn't necessarily remove it if you don't need to use await. See Sebastian's answer.
